# Javascript mode compatible with es6

Tags: major-mode, javascript

Does anyone know of a javascript editing mode that supports the [es6 syntax additions](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#readme) (arrow functions, extends, imports, generators, etc.)? I've done some quick searching but it looks like so far everyone just uses `js2-mode` and ignores the syntax errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind installing some npm modules it looks like eslint+flycheck could do the trick like described [here](http://codewinds.com/blog/2015-04-02-emacs-flycheck-eslint-jsx.html).